# How to identify duplicate records in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I want to identify the documents having duplicate values in MarkLogic. I have an xml like below and `BillNo` is the primary key for a document, I need to find out is there any documents is having duplicate `BillNo` ie. Occurrence of the same `BillNo` multiple times across multiple documents.

```
<BillData>
  <Date>20211112</Date>
  <BillNo>123</BillNo>
  <Description>ABC</Description>
</BillData>
```

I am using XQuery for coding

Answer (score 2):

If you have a range index on the BillNo, then you could use [`cts:values()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:values) get a distinct list of BillingNo values and filter for the ones that appear more than once using [`cts:frequency()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:frequency):

```
for $value in cts:values(cts:element-reference(xs:QName("BillNo")))
where cts:frequency($value) gt 1
return $value
```

If you wanted to list the URIs of the documents that have the same BillingNo, then you could use [`cts:element-value-co-occurrences`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-co-occurrences) for `BillingNo` and `xdmp:document`. If you use the `map` option to return the results as a map with the `BillingNo` as the key and the document URI(s) as the value(s), you could remove the entries that have only one corresponding URI, and then would have a map that lists the `BillingNo` used in multiple documents and their URIs.

```
let $co-occurrences := cts:element-value-co-occurrences(xs:QName("BillNo"), xs:QName("xdmp:document"), "map")
let $_remove_entries_with_only_one_uri :=
  for $key in map:keys($co-occurrences)
  where map:get($co-occurrences, $key) => tail()
  return map:put($co-occurrences, $key, ())
return
  $co-occurrences
```

If you don't have an index, then you **might** be able to do something like this, but run the risk of Expanded Tree Cache errors:

```
let $dups := map:new()
let $_ :=
  for $value in /BillData/BillNo/string()
  return map:put($dups, $value, head((map:get($dups, $value), 0)) + 1)
let $values-by-count := -$dups  
let $_remove_entries_with_only_one_uri:= map:put($values-by-count, "1", ())
return 
(: flip the map back to values as keys, get BillingNo that have occurred multiple times :)
  map:keys(-$values-by-count)
```

Comment: You can also return the values in frequency-order so highest frequency of value occurrence is listed first. If the first returned value has a frequency of 1 you could then not bother checking the rest of the Sequence.